How to find the arn on the console
I have a arn: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:XXXXXXX:automl-job/auto-insurence-test12345
the above is created using the below lambda
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Initialize the SageMaker client
    sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

    # Define parameters for the AutoPilot job
    job_name = 'auto-insurence-test12345'  # Change this to your desired job name
    target_attribute_name = 'charges'  # Change this to your target column name
    input_data_config = [{
        'DataSource': {
            'S3DataSource': {
                'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
                'S3Uri': 's3://automldyd/insurance.csv',  # Change to your input data
            }
        },
        'TargetAttributeName': target_attribute_name  # Specify the target attribute name
    }]
    output_data_config = {
        'S3OutputPath': 's3://automldyd/',  # Change to your output bucket
    }

    # Create the AutoPilot job
    try:
        response = sagemaker_client.create_auto_ml_job(
            AutoMLJobName=job_name,
            InputDataConfig=input_data_config,
            OutputDataConfig=output_data_config,
            RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/AmazonSageMaker-role-dyd',  # Change to your IAM role
    
            AutoMLJobConfig={
                'CompletionCriteria': {
                    'MaxCandidates': 5,  # Change as needed
                    'MaxRuntimePerTrainingJobInSeconds': 3600,  # Change as needed
                },
                
                'Mode': 'AUTO'  # Can be 'AUTOMATED' or 'ENSEMBLE'
            }
        )
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': 'AutoPilot job started successfully',
                'AutoMLJobArn': response['AutoMLJobArn']
            })
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': 'Failed to start AutoPilot job',
                'error': str(e)
            })
        }



Now searched sagemaker in aws console and dont know where to see the details of the arn arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:XXXXXXX:automl-job/auto-insurence-test12345
can someone guide me
What I checked is

i can see some processing jobs are created

I can see some s3 bucket of the job name is also created and filled with some folders


In which region your lambda is deployed ?

us-east-2  my lambda is in
